# Gatsby markdown blockquote looks the same, isn't working, isn't quoted, isn't a block

Tags: javascript, markdown, gatsby

I have my markdown file, and apparently [this is how you're supposed to style blockquotes](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#blockquotes-1), with a > in front

```
-----------------------
title: some title
img: some img
-------------------------

A paragraph

> This is an example of a block quote

This is an example of some **bolded text**
```

But the block-quote looks just like all the other regular text

[image]

How can I get my block-quote to look like it does in the link I provided?

---

I included my gatsby-config.js and gatsby-node.js file in case they provide any helpful information

**gatsby-config.js**

```js
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `my title`,
    description: `My description`,
    author: `Me`,
    authorDescription: "Me",
    themeColor: "#111111",
    siteUrl: "example.com",
    image: "my_image.png"
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader",
      options: {
        google: {
          families: ["Mansalva", "Playfair Display", "Source Sans Pro"],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src/assets/images`),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/markdown/`,
        name: `markdown-pages`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
      options: { prefixes: [
        `/contact/*`,
        `/partners/*`,
        `/publications/*`
      ] },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#fff`,
        theme_color: `#542C85`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/assets/images/gatsby-icon.png`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              linkImagesToOriginal: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-root-import',
      options: {
        "components": path.join(__dirname, "src/components"),
        // "layouts": path.join(__dirname, "src/layouts"),
        "styles": path.join(__dirname, "src/assets/styles"),
        "types": path.join(__dirname, "src/types"),
        "enums": path.join(__dirname, "src/enums"),
        "interfaces": path.join(__dirname, "src/interfaces"),
        "data": path.join(__dirname, 'src/data'),
        "pages": path.join(__dirname, 'src/pages')
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-graphql-loader`
  ],
}
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```js
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require('gatsby-remark-relative-images');
const path = require("path")

const replacePath = path => (path === `/` ? path : path.replace(/\/$/, ``))

exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage }, graphql }) => {
  const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/components/Article/index.tsx`)

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
 
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (result.errors) {
    return Promise.reject(result.errors)
  }

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: replacePath(node.fields.slug),
      component: postTemplate,
    })
  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  fmImagesToRelative(node)
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`)
    actions.createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: replacePath(createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })),
    })
  
}
```

Comment: What HTML is generated? What does the CSS do to blockquotes?

Comment: yeah, you need to use the same css as the example. gatsby only creates the <blockquote> element. How it displays is up to the css

Comment: @GarrGodfrey The example doesn't have any CSS, at least not that I can see

Comment: @Quentin What CSS?

Comment: @Sam — If there wasn't any CSS it would look like https://jsbin.com/wegolujaye/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example has css styles applied. Specifically:

```
blockquote {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1.5em 10px;
    padding: 1em 10px .1em 10px;
    quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
```

Use similar css to make blockquotes look the same where you display it.

Comment: I see, I figured it was just supposed to happen because all the other markdown parts converted without any additional setup. In the article blockquotes seems like it's the one thing where they don't show the converted html.